# Phonegap back button not working when cursor focus on a field

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I overide the backbutton event on my apps javascript like this:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.app.backHistory();
}, false);
```

If the cursor is not focussed on any element that exists on the webview (CordovaWebView), pressing the back button is fine, in my case it back to previous Activity.

But, if cursor is focussed on a field form, e.g. input field or button, back button is not working or just hide the keyboard. The logcat only show this, when i pressed the back button.

```
05-13 12:47:41.463: D/CordovaWebView(14396): The current URL is: file:///android_asset/www/login.html#register
05-13 12:47:41.463: D/CordovaWebView(14396): The URL at item 0 is:file:///android_asset/www/login.html#register
05-13 12:47:41.663: D/CordovaWebView(14396): The current URL is: file:///android_asset/www/login.html#register
05-13 12:47:41.663: D/CordovaWebView(14396): The URL at item 0 is:file:///android_asset/www/login.html#register
05-13 12:47:42.203: D/CordovaWebView(14396): The current URL is: file:///android_asset/www/login.html#register
05-13 12:47:42.203: D/CordovaWebView(14396): The URL at item 0 is:file:///android_asset/www/login.html#register
```

I've tried override the onBackPressed on the DroidGap extension but makes it not working at all.

**Edit**

I forget to say, I'm using Backbone Router for the url state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "backbutton" event is fired only when the button is pressed to navigate back, not when used to close the keyboard.

The closest you can get is intercepting the window resize due to the keyboard close and react accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var curWindow = $(window);
    var initialHeight = curWindow.height();
    curWindow.resize(function() {
        console.log("resize: height="+curWindow.height());
        if (curWindow.height() == initialHeight) {
      // TODO: Keyboard hidden!
        } 
    });
});
```